# What is the pdf of g(x,y) were x and y are two random variables from a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

Is there a formula analogous to the single random variable case i.e the pdf of y(x) where x is generated from a pdf=f(x) is given by:
$g(y)=f(x(y))|\frac{dx}{dy}|$ ?

Specifically, I have the following problem:
X,Y are two uniform distributions with $a<x<b$ and $c<y<d$. Find the pdf of $Z=\frac{1-r^2}{1+\rho^2}$ where $r=\sqrt2\rho$ and $\rho=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$

Answer (score -1):

There is no general formula (that I know of), (unless, you mean the this one, which is the definition):
$$P(z)=\int\delta\Big(z-g(x,y)\Big)P(x,y)dx\,dy$$
$\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution, $P(x,y)$ is the (joint) PDF of $X$ and $Y$ and $P(z)$ is the PDF of $Z$.

However, your problem is relatively simple as you can first calculate the PDF of $\rho$ and then use the formula you cited for $Z$. The PDF of $\rho$, unfortunately, is not very nice. You can get the answer for $a=c=0$ and $b=d=1$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394775/if-mathbf-x-is-sampled-randomly-from-a-hypercube-on-rn-what-is-the-probab/394910#394910), and you can probably generalize it to other cases, but it will not be nice.

Comment: Hmmm... In the present case, $P(Z=z)=0$ for every $z$.

Comment: @Did Why? $P(\rho)$ is finite for $\sqrt{a^2+c^2}<z<\sqrt{b^2+d^2}$, $P(Z)$ is just a transformation of $P(\rho)$

Comment: Because every random variable $X$ with a PDF is such that $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$.

Comment: @did yeah, it's a typo. I meant the PDF. Fixed that

Comment: And now, what we have is a formula which hides the difficulty under the rug by using the Dirac delta, whose precise meaning in this context is unlikely to be grasped by nonexperts.